# Clear Firefox Developer Edition DNS Cache on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, firefox, dns, hosts

When I change `/etc/hosts` file, the changes are ignored by Mozilla Firefox.
For example, I use `0.0.0.0 facebook.com` to ban Facebook. This works perfectly in Chromium or when I try to ping it from terminal. But no matter what I do, Firefox always shows Facebook.

What I tried:

- restarting Firefox / rebooting system
- `/etc/init.d/networking restart`
- setting `network.dnsCacheExpiration` to 0 in `about:config` in browser
- restarting nscd
- using DNS Flusher addon - absolutely no effect
- editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364626)
- `chmod 0644 /etc/hosts` according to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/67159/267464)
- and also everything else that I've found by Googling in first 3 pages of results

Any other ideas please? I believe this is caused by Firefox caching DNS, but I don't know how to clear it. Any other browser/client behaves according to `/etc/hosts`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "Forget about this site" option in Firefox?

> You can remove all data stored in Firefox from a specific domain via
>   "Forget About This Site" in the right-click context menu of an history
>   entry ("History > Show All History" or "View > Sidebar > History") or
>   via the about:permissions page.
>
> Using "Forget About This Site" will remove all data stored in Firefox
>   from that domain like bookmarks, cookies, passwords, cache, history,
>   and exceptions, so be cautious and if you have a password or other
>   data from that domain that you do not want to lose then make sure to
>   backup this data or make a note.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1015370#answer-615732

This solved a problem for me when Firefox had cached no longer existing redirects of a URL.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help :(

Comment: Worked for my related problem: Everything *but* `google.com` was working. Did this, restart Firefox, worked like a charm.